# Accessing Plist items in a dict

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, plist

I have a class in a module I that reads a plist (XML) file and returns a dict. This is extremely convenient because I can say something like:

```
Data.ServerNow.Property().DefaultChart
```

This returns a property dictionary, specifically the value for `DefaultChart`. Very elegant.
However, assembling a dictionary this way fails:

```
dict={'Data': 'text1', 'Name':'text2', 'Place':'text3]}
```

`dict` looks exactly like the Plist dict.
But when I say

```
print TextNow.Data().Name
```

I get error

```
 'dict' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

But if I say

```
print TextNow.Data()['Name']
```

suddenly it works!

Can someone explain this behavior? Is there a way to  convert a dict to an XML-ish dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getattr redefinition to treat dictionary keys as attributes, e.g.:

```
class xmldict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            if attr in self:
                return self[attr]
            else:
                raise
```

So, for example if you will have following dict:

```
dict_ = {'a':'some text'}
```

You can do so:

```
>> print xmldict(dict_).a
some text
>> print xmldict(dict_).NonExistent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: 'xmldict' object has no attribute 'NonExistent'
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the dot operator is not proper accessor syntax for python dictionaries.  You;re trying to treat it as an object and access a property, rather than accessing a data member of the data structure.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was easier to write the plist and load that file into a dict, which I had to do anyway.